# How can I add "complex" URL attachments to a card via Trello’s API?

Tags: trello, javascript

On Trello's API documentation, it is said that an `urlSource` parameter can be included while creating cards. This can be found [here](https://developers.trello.com/reference/#cards-2). I'm testing the API with JavaScript.

The problem is that Trello doesn't seem to decode this `urlSource` field properly when I use complex URLs with parameters of their own.

For example:
`http://www.myurl.com/script.php?arg1=value1&arg2=value2&arg3=value3`

From my experience, I can achieve two results:

1. If I encode the URL using JavaScript's `encodeURIComponent` function, Trello doesn't decode the URL at all.
   Result: `http://http%3A%2F%2Fwww.myurl.com%2Fscript.php%3Farg1%3Dvalue1%26arg2%3Dvalue2%26arg3%3Dvalue3`
2. If I don't encode the URL, Trello crops it on the first `&` (meaning that only `arg1` would be preserved.
   Result: `http://www.myurl.com/script.php?arg1=value1`

Can someone shed a little light on this?

Comment: This question has been bumped by Community user ten times. Questions about APIs are off-topic here; these questions might be on-topic in [so].

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by using the url encoding for the &.
Looks something like :
http://www.myurl.com/script.php%26arg1=value1%26arg2=value2%26arg3=value3